# How to guarantee that my Kubernetes EBS volume will be in the same AZ as the deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-ebs

I have a k8s cluster on AWS (3 nodes, across `us-east-1a`, `us-east-1b` and `us-east-1c`) and I'm trying to use an `awsElasticBlockStore` volume but I keep getting a `InvalidVolume.ZoneMismatch` error.

I create the volume via `aws-cli`:

`aws ec2 create-volume --availability-zone us-east-1a --size 10`

I wait for it to become `available` then deploy my k8s deployment that has it mapped like so:

`volumes:
  - name: myVol
    awsElasticBlockStore:
      volumeID: <volume-id-from-above>
      fsType: ext4`

How can I guarantee that my EBS volume will be in the same AZ as the deployment? Is it via the deployment spec, or is there a better way to create/provision the `awsElasticBlockStore` that I'm overlooking?

Comment: For the time being, I've deployed a new cluster without HA, all on a single AZ, but hoping there's a better solution to this overall.

Comment: From kubernetes  version 1.6 and onwards you dont need to create EBS volume manually. Create a PVC and it will automatically create a AWS volume for you with the required size and in same region which can easily be attached to your nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From kubernetes  version 1.6 and onwards you don't need to create EBS volume manually. Create a PVC and it will automatically create a AWS volume for you with the required size and in the same region which can easily be attached to your nodes.

Comment: What if Pod reschedules on west-2b but PVC is still running on west-2a ?

Comment: This does not answer the question about how to ensure a deployment and persistentvolumeclaim are scheduled in the same AZ.  I was hoping there was a way to include the persistentvolumeclaim in the deployment or pd spec